# how to loop thru a table to find data set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to find the timediff in minutes for a order lifetime.
i.e time from order was received(Activity ID 1) to keyed(2) to printed(3) to delivered(4) for each order

for eg

I am completely lost at which approach should i take??
 use case or if then statement ?? something like for each to loop thru each record? 
what should be the most efficient way to do it?

i know once i get dates in correct variables i can use DATEDIFF.

```
declare @received as Datetime, @keyed as DateTime, @printed as Datetime, @Delivered as Datetime, @TurnTime1 as int
Select
IF (tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = 1) SET @received = tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate
---
----
from tblOrderActivity
where OrderID = 1
```

it should show me @TurnTime1  =  48 mins as orderID 1 took 48 mins from received(activity id 1) to keyed  (activity id 2) @TurnTime2 = 29 mins as it took 29mins for order 1 from keyed(activity id 2) to printed (activity id 3) so on and so forth for each order

Comment: What would be the desired output?

Comment: it should show me @TurnTime1  =  48 mins as orderID 1 took 48 mins from received(activity id 1) to keyed  (activity id 2)

Comment: case works on various columns in the same record. You need to do a self join on this table to join from one record to the next before you can use a case statement. Can a state ever be repeated or missing? i.e. can you have 2 3's or can you be missing a 2? Also if this is SQL Server, get rid of the Oracle tag.

Comment: Do you have only 4 Activity IDs? Is this set of IDs fixed / hardcoded?

Comment: yes it comes form a master table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily by `pivoting` the data.It can be done in two ways.

1.Use `Conditional Aggregate` to pivot the data. After `pivoting` you can find `datediff` between different stages. Try this.

```
SELECT orderid,Received,Keyed,Printed,Delivered,
       Datediff(minute, Received, Keyed)    TurnTime1,
       Datediff(minute, Keyed, Printed)     TurnTime2,
       Datediff(minute, Printed, Delivered) TurnTime3
FROM  (SELECT OrderID,
              Max(CASE WHEN ActivityID = 1 THEN ActivityDate END) Received,
              Max(CASE WHEN ActivityID = 2 THEN ActivityDate END) Keyed,
              Max(CASE WHEN ActivityID = 3 THEN ActivityDate END) Printed,
              Max(CASE WHEN ActivityID = 4 THEN ActivityDate END) Delivered
       FROM   Yourtable
       GROUP  BY OrderID)A
```

2.use `Pivot` to transpose the data

```
SELECT orderid,
       [1]                        AS Received,
       [2]                        AS Keyed,
       [3]                        AS Printed,
       [4]                        AS Delivered,
       Datediff(minute, [1], [2]) TurnTime1,
       Datediff(minute, [2], [3]) TurnTime2,
       Datediff(minute, [3], [4]) TurnTime3
FROM   Yourtable
       PIVOT (Max(ActivityDate)
             FOR ActivityID IN([1],[2],[3],[4]))piv
```

Comment: this works !! can you please elaborate more on how the query will work especially number 1 ?? sorry for my ignorance, but i wish to understand it better,

Comment: @Rash - check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310674/Conditional-Sums-in-SQL-Aggregate-Methods

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question, one possible way is to use `CASE` statement

```
DECLARE @i INT, @max INT
SELECT @i = MIN(OrderId) FROM tblOrderActivity
SELECT @max = MAX(OrderId) from tblOrderActivity

WHILE @i <= @max
BEGIN
SELECT OrderId
       ,ActivityID
       ,ActivityDate
       ,CASE
        WHEN ActivityID = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActivityDate, (SELECT ActivityDate FROM C WHERE ActivityID = 2 AND OrderId = @i))
        END AS tokeyed
       ,CASE
        WHEN ActivityID = 2 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActivityDate, (SELECT ActivityDate FROM C WHERE ActivityID = 3 AND OrderId = @i))
        END AS toprinted
       ,CASE
        WHEN ActivityID = 3 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActivityDate, (SELECT ActivityDate FROM C WHERE ActivityID = 4 AND OrderId = @i))
        END AS todelivered
FROM tblOrderActivity

SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: thanks, but this will give me datediff from datetime now, i want timediff between activitydates of same order but different activityID

Answer (score 1):

At first I make a list of all orders (`CTE_Orders`).

For each order I get four dates, one for each ActivityID using `OUTER APPLY`. I assume that some activities could be missing (not completed yet), so `OUTER APPLY` would return `NULL` there. When I calculate durations I assume that if activity is not in the database, it hasn't happened yet and I calculate duration till the current time. You can handle this case differently if you have other requirements.

I assume that each order can have at most one row for each `Activity ID`. If you can have two or more rows with the same `Order ID` and `Activity ID`, then you need to decide which one to pick by adding `ORDER BY` to the `SELECT` inside the  `OUTER APPLY`.

```
DECLARE @TOrders TABLE (OrderID int, ActivityID int, ActivityDate datetime);

INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (1, 1, '2007-04-16T08:34:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (1, 1, '2007-04-16T08:34:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (1, 2, '2007-04-16T09:22:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (1, 3, '2007-04-16T09:51:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (1, 4, '2007-04-16T16:14:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (2, 1, '2007-04-16T08:34:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (3, 1, '2007-04-16T08:34:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (3, 2, '2007-04-16T09:22:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (3, 3, '2007-04-16T09:51:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (3, 4, '2007-04-16T16:14:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (4, 1, '2007-04-16T08:34:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (4, 2, '2007-04-16T09:22:00');
INSERT INTO @TOrders (OrderID, ActivityID, ActivityDate) VALUES (4, 3, '2007-04-16T09:51:00');

WITH
CTE_Orders
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Orders.OrderID
    FROM @TOrders AS Orders
)
SELECT
    CTE_Orders.OrderID
    ,Date1_Received
    ,Date2_Keyed
    ,Date3_Printed
    ,Date4_Delivered
    ,DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL(Date1_Received, GETDATE()), ISNULL(Date2_Keyed, GETDATE())) AS Time12
    ,DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL(Date2_Keyed, GETDATE()), ISNULL(Date3_Printed, GETDATE())) AS Time23
    ,DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL(Date3_Printed, GETDATE()), ISNULL(Date4_Delivered, GETDATE())) AS Time34
FROM
    CTE_Orders
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) Orders.ActivityDate AS Date1_Received
        FROM @TOrders AS Orders
        WHERE
            Orders.OrderID = CTE_Orders.OrderID
            AND Orders.ActivityID = 1
    ) AS OA1_Received
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) Orders.ActivityDate AS Date2_Keyed
        FROM @TOrders AS Orders
        WHERE
            Orders.OrderID = CTE_Orders.OrderID
            AND Orders.ActivityID = 2
    ) AS OA2_Keyed
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) Orders.ActivityDate AS Date3_Printed
        FROM @TOrders AS Orders
        WHERE
            Orders.OrderID = CTE_Orders.OrderID
            AND Orders.ActivityID = 3
    ) AS OA3_Printed
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) Orders.ActivityDate AS Date4_Delivered
        FROM @TOrders AS Orders
        WHERE
            Orders.OrderID = CTE_Orders.OrderID
            AND Orders.ActivityID = 4
    ) AS OA4_Delivered
ORDER BY OrderID;
```

This the result set:

```
OrderID    Date1_Received             Date2_Keyed                Date3_Printed              Date4_Delivered            Time12    Time23    Time34
1          2007-04-16 08:34:00.000    2007-04-16 09:22:00.000    2007-04-16 09:51:00.000    2007-04-16 16:14:00.000    48        29        383
2          2007-04-16 08:34:00.000    NULL                       NULL                       NULL                       4082575   0         0
3          2007-04-16 08:34:00.000    2007-04-16 09:22:00.000    2007-04-16 09:51:00.000    2007-04-16 16:14:00.000    48        29        383
4          2007-04-16 08:34:00.000    2007-04-16 09:22:00.000    2007-04-16 09:51:00.000    NULL                       48        29        4082498
```

You can easily calculate other durations, like the total time for the order (time 4 - time1).

Once you have several different queries that produce the same correct result that you need you should measure their performance with your real data on your system to decide which is more efficient.

Comment: Why you need `Getdate()` in `DateDiff`. also you are suggesting the longest route to find the answer

Comment: @NoDisplayName. It depends on requirements. I assumed that if there is no activity with a certain ID, then this activity hasn't happened **yet** and duration to this activity is duration to the current time. If the logic is different, the `NULL`s should be processed differently.  In terms of performance it is really necessary to measure different variants on real system and real data. `PIVOT` is definitely another good variant.

Answer (score 0):

this one should fill your needs, but I would suggest to use this query while you insert the values into the table and directly add this value in a new column

```
SELECT OrderID,
       ActivityID,
       ActivityDate,
       Datediff(MINUTE, ActivityDate, (SELECT ActivityDate
                                       FROM   [TestDB].[dbo].[tblOrderActivity] AS b
                                       WHERE  b.OrderID = a.OrderID
                                              AND a.ActivityID + 1 = b.ActivityID))
FROM   [TestDB].[dbo].[tblOrderActivity] AS a
```