# Get records according to a datetime difference between associated records with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables

» Item

- Id
- CreatedOn
- Type
- ...

» StatusChange

- StatusId
- StatusChangedOn
- Status
- ItemId

An item can have multiple statuschanges. I want to see how long it takes for the status to change from one specific status to another for a certain selection of items.
Specifically I want to know when statuschanges take more than 30 minutes.

What I did so far is this:
Create a temp table with items from the needed daterange

```
INSERT #tempSC2
SELECT ItemId FROM StatusChange sc2 WHERE sc2.Status = 'Requested' AND
sc2.CreatedOn >= '2015-01-12' AND sc2.CreatedOn < '2015-01-19'
```

Select all the statuschanges from these items, where the status equals the two statusses of which I need to calculate the difference in time and where the type of item is the wanted type.

```
INSERT #tempSC
SELECT sc.ItemId, sc.Status, sc.StatusChangedOn, i.Type
FROM StatusChange sc
INNER JOIN Item i ON sc.ItemId = i.ID
WHERE (i.Type = 'TypeX' OR i.Type = 'TypeY')
AND (sc.Status = 'Requested' OR sc.Status = 'Finished')
AND sc.ItemId IN (SELECT * FROM #tempSC2)
ORDER BY sc.ItemId
```

So now I have a list with only the needed statuschanges (one record for 'Requested' and one for 'Finished' with the same ItemId, and so on, its also possible there is a 'Requested' record but no 'Finished' record), but I need to get the difference in time between Requested and Finished for each ItemId and show all itemId's for which the difference in time betweens its statuschanges (only Requested and Finished statuschanges) is more than 20 mintues.

I'm not sure how to continue.. What could be my next step? I don't see any immediate possibilities using aggregates and group by.

Comment: check out DATEDIFF()

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch Thanks, I understand datediff but the problem is how do I datediff/compare status1's statuschangedon field with status2's statuschangedon field of item1 in a query and do this for all items?

Comment: very similar question was answered recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016136/how-to-loop-thru-a-table-to-find-data-set